# Using HTML5 Boilerplate Build script with a PHP framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, fuelphp

I’m a big fan of the popular HTML5 Boilerplate. I’d love to use the build script to minifiy etc, but I can’t figure out how to get everything working together. To add further fun, I deploy using Git – no FTP.

Paul Irish’s video on using the build script is great, and at the end he shows a way to deploy on a server, then use .htaccess to reroot traffic from .com/ to .com/published/site/ – however that doesn’t really work when you’ve got a webapp and you’re using views. It’s also a really bad habit to put any code in public_html.

So here’s the structure I’m after of the deployed and built site:

```
- webapp
   - app
      - classes
          - welcome.php
      - views
          - template.php
   - framework
- public_html
   - index.php
   - css
   - js
   - img
```

But it needs to:

- Be still able to develop locally, without having to build every time!
- Be Gitable – deploy to server, then build
- Minify and read views from webapp

My first attempt ended up like this:

```
- webapp
   - app
      - classes
          - welcome.php
      - views
          - template.php
   - framework
- public_html
   - index.php
   - css (minified)
   - js (minified)
   - img (minified)
- dev_html
   - index.php
   - build
          - etc...
   - css
   - js
   - img
```

Then I published back up, but then completely forgot about the fact that the HTML file that needs reading is in the webapp, so then I get stuck.

It’s a bit complicated so do ask if you don’t get it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Michell’s suggestion of using CodeIgniter/HTML5 Boilerplate by Serkan Sökmen is pretty close, but the problem is that it publishes it to a folder within itself, which if you published on a server (after deploy via Git), would mean the app is in public_html – bad for security.

I’ve started a topic about it in the issues at HTML5 Boilerplate if anybody’s interested. Not figure it out yet:
https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/558

**Edit! Updated!**

I’ve created a GitHut repo for the files I’ve changed:
https://github.com/thomasedwards/h5bp-publish-tree

It pretty much works the way I intended it to, might be worth something to somebody.

Comment: Nice, good on you for posting your solution up on github for others.

Answer (score 3):

Since your using Git anyway, check out Serkan Sökmen's github branch where he's got CI and HTML5 Boilerplate working together: [Codeigniter---HTML5-Boilerplate](https://github.com/serkansokmen/Codeigniter---HTML5-Boilerplate)

Comment: That’s a good start! The problem is it publishes the entire thing to a `publish` folder, which assumes you’re going to then upload it via FTP. A little hacking and it might just work! The way they’ve split the header and footer and then built off those is good.